# Why are there no DOIs for NeurIPS papers?

Tags: publications, conference, doi

It is nowadays pretty standard to have a DOI with every item-to-be-cited (papers, algorithms, data, etc.), and they are really useful for all kinds of purposes. Considering this, I am quite surprised to be unable to find DOIs for NeurIPS papers, especially considering that it is one of the major CS conferences... Is there a reason for this?

Related question: [Why do some papers not have a DOI?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23508/61059) The highest voted answer there relates to the time/cost required to obtain a DOI, both of which I would assume not to be an issue for NeurIPS...

Answer (score 12):

I work at Crossref (there are other DOI agencies too) and it looks like the proceedings used to be published by MIT Press and registered with Crossref as book chapters - see [search results](https://search.crossref.org/?q=%22Advances%20in%20Neural%20Information%20Processing%20Systems%22&publication=Advances%20in%20Neural%20Information%20Processing%20Systems%22). But there isn't anything with us since 2007 so not sure whether the conference moved to a new publisher that isn't a Crossref member or something like that? I searched the [ISBN database](https://isbnsearch.org/search?s=%22Advances%20in%20Neural%20Information%20Processing%2520Systems%2522%26publication%3DAdvances%2520in%2520Neural%20Information%20Processing%20Systems%22&p=2) too but that doesn't help much. Probably best to ask the conference/organisation directly? Let me know if you find out!

Comment: NeurIPS seems to be publishing with Curran Associates (https://www.proceedings.com), which I have frankly never heard of. Curran seems to offering DOIs, but maybe NeurIPS is not taking them up on this offer?