# Which software can check on false references and incorrect citation on student papers?

Tags: citations, writing, software, generative-ai

I'm a TA at a medium-sized university in Asia, and as part of my routine, I randomly review student papers before using Turnitin for plagiarism checks. During these reviews, I've come across numerous errors related to citation formatting, including instances where references contain non-existent links. I suspect some students may be using AI writing tools like ChatGPT to generate their papers. To address this issue, I first need to assess the extent of the problem. However, considering the large class size of over 50 students, I'm wondering if there's a tool available that can automatically detect and flag false references or incorrect citations in their papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution after researching for a while, I will suggest this to my professor and the Chair of the department.
https://www.scribbr.com/citation/checker/

Answer (score 0):

I would require students to provide a list of DOIs and URLs.  DOIs can be checked with these instructions: https://dx.doi.org/

For books, students can provide an ISBN.  Those are a bit trickier to validate, but could help.

Comment: In machine learning DOIs are not universally assigned at very relevant venues like NeurIPS: [link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151409/why-are-there-no-dois-for-neurips-papers). This might make it hard to demand DOIs universally.

Comment: @MarkusLange-Hegermann Which is why I did not recommend that.  NeurIPS has both URLs and an ISBN for their most recent proceedings.

Comment: That might help with the false references, but it will be a daunting task if students write papers with 20 pages with 50 references and above. Also, will you ignore the miscitation? Probably I will ignore a few, but not about 25 miscitations and above

Comment: @throwawayta From experience, DOIs are massively easier to use in writing than traditional citations.